# Shiny APP is showing last retrieved mysql data

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

Below is my Shiny code where i am making connection to remote mysql db. I get the correct result first time then when I have new rows in mysql db shiny still shows old data even if I run in different browsers.

#load libraries

```
library(stringr)
library(twitteR)
library(plyr)
library(ROAuth)
library(base64enc)
library(shiny)
require(RJSONIO)
library(RMySQL) # will load DBI as well

options(shiny.sanitize.errors = FALSE)

lapply( dbListConnections( dbDriver( drv = "MySQL")), dbDisconnect)

con <- dbConnect(dbDriver("MySQL"), user = "user_name", password = "passowrd", dbname = "db_name", host="remotehost.org")

on.exit(dbDisconnect(con))
```

### saving the data in test variable

```
test <- dbGetQuery(con, paste("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE columnname = '","'"))
```

# displaying data on browser

```
ui <- fluidPage(textOutput(outputId="jsonoutput"))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$jsonoutput <- renderText({
    toJSON(list(NLP =  test))
  })


}

dbDisconnect(con)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put the query inside the server function otherwise it is run only at the initialization of the app. You might also add an actionButton.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton("action","Action Button"),
    textOutput(outputId="jsonoutput")
)

server <- function(input, output) { 
  test <- eventReactive(input$action,{ dbGetQuery(con, paste("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE  
                                           columnname = '","'"))  
  })  
  output$jsonoutput <- renderText({
            toJSON(list(NLP =  test()))
            }) 
}
```